# MySQL function to convert a text field encoded with Latin1 to UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, latin1

I want to convert my current MySQL database encoded with `latin1` to a new database encoded with `utf-8`.

How could I import my old data (text fields) correctly to the tables of the new database with `utf-8` encoding? 
I thought I can use a query as follows:

```
insert into newTable (newField) select latin2utf8(oldField) 
from oldTable
```

What I am looking for is a SQL function or a combination of functions which works as `latin2utf8` mentioned in the query.

Is there any SQL method for converting data as I described, to be used in this command?

Comment: Please consider my modified question and answer, the problem is clearly stated!

Comment: This is being discussed on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284934/my-question-was-closed-while-a-similar-question-is-open-a-poin-on-the-problem). It was deleted, but I've undeleted it to facilitate discussion on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the query that is reading rows from the old database, first, convert the column to binary, then convert it back to utf8 as follows:

```
select convert(binary convert(field_name using latin1) using utf8) 
from table_name
```